# Add query string to plugin URL

Tags: plugins, urls

I am creating a plugin that resides at http://localhost/test/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=my-plugin

I am trying to add a query string to this page so that it can be used in my plugin such as http://localhost/test/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=my-plugin?myVar=cool

The problem is that this prompts wordpress to display the "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." page.

How can I add a query string to my plugin URL? Is this documented someplace?

thanks for the help.

Comment: Nevermind, I just took another look at the url and it looks like the query string has already been started so the answer is 

http://localhost/test/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=my-plugin&myVar=cool

WHOOPS!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you don't know if query string was started or not you can use [**add_query_arg**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg)
which it knows how to deal with that and adds the "`?`" or "`&`" marks (which ever one is needed) to the query string.

### Update

By popular demand I'm adding a few examples that are from the codex:

**Using get_permalink:**

> Since get_permalink() returns a full
>   URL, you could use that when you want
>   to add variables to a post's page.

```
//  This would output whatever the URL to post ID 9 is, with 'hello=there' appended with either ? or &, depending on what's needed
echo add_query_arg( 'hello', 'there', get_permalink(9) );
```

**more general:**

> Assuming we're at the WordPress URL
>   `"http://blog.example.com/client/?s=word"...`

```
//  This would output '/client/?s=word&foo=bar'
echo add_query_arg( 'foo', 'bar' );

//  This would output '/client/?s=word&foo=bar&baz=tiny'
$arr_params = array ( 'foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'tiny' );
echo add_query_arg( $arr_params );
```

Or for use with any link you have you can pass the link uri:

```
//say your link is: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14827/
//then use:

echo add_query_arg( 'hello', 'world','http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14827/');
```

to get `http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14827/?hello=world`

**Example plugin page URL with extra query args:**

```
$query_args = array( 'page' => 'your-plugin-page', 'foo' => 'bar' );
echo add_query_arg( $query_args, admin_url( '/options-general.php' ) )

// outputs
// http://example.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=your-plugin-page&foo=bar
```

Comment: Nice. Beat me to it. Want to add an example of how to use the function? It might help to see it in action, since there are several valid ways of using it.

Comment: I added a few examples, but feel free to edit and add more.

Comment: I've added another.. ;)